# При использовании простых ссылок WordPress не выдает 404

Tags: php, wordpress, ссылки

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Если ставить в настройках WordPress простые ссылки, то вместо шаблона 404 открывает обычную ошибку "Not Found
The requested URL /aadsad was not found on this server."
Использование простых ссылок обязательно, подскажите как исправить эту проблему.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В настройках WP (да и в документации нет такого понятия, как простые ссылки). Поясните, чего вы хотите, пользуясь стандартными терминами. Приведите пост, который неправильно отображается, настройку постоянных ссылок. В общем, задайте вопрос по-человечески.

Comment: Иными словами, создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @KAGGDesign простые - это дефолтные в настройках пермалинков.

Comment: @SeVlad об этом можно только догадываться. Нет такого термина - простые ссылки. А если есть, покажите, где он описан в официальных документах.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а зайти в пермалинки - что там написано? :)

Comment: Да, и правда, на русском - написано )) А по-английски - plain )) Не думал, что так переведут) С этим разобрались - а  с вопросом-то что делать? )))

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, так и будет. Для задания своей 404й страницы нужно в `.htaccess` вручную прописать директиву

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Где `404.html` файл в корне сайта (не темы ВП!)